# What verb naturally fits in discussing the phrase "crime wave"?

Tags: word-choice, collocations

> According to many, long sentences cannot tackle the sheer scale of the
> crime wave.

Which one of the following sentences corresponds with "crime wave"?

1. tackle
2. fight
3. manage
4. stop

As we fight or tackle crime, I guess we can also fight or tackle crime wave. We also can manage it I think.

But I need a perfect word that shows that I am considering crime deterrents.

Comment: Do you want a verb that collocates with "the sheer scale" or with "the crime wave"? In this sentence, it collocates with "the sheer scale".

Answer (score 0):

I view dealing with crime as management and none of the other options.

Dealing with crime requires changes that are proactive in nature, like implementing better education. Fighting requires more reaction than proaction. It's like treating symptoms of a virus rather than eradicating that virus. Good management requires much proaction, the connotation just matches much better. We aren't trying to create more violence, more fights, we are trying to *curtail* these issues.

Comment: Some of these are wrong because the verb applies to "the sheer scale", not "crime wave". One can indeed fight or stop a crime wave, but it's an odd usage to fight or stop the scale of something.